# Connect WinDbg to vmware

Tags: vmware, windbg

I am learning about windows internals. I want to do a kernel debug from windDBg. I created a port on COM1: with port mode as Host Device. I am running windows 7 in debug mode with the virtual box. My computer is running windows 10. I go to file > kernel debug > COM. My settings are Pipe and Reconnect selected. Port is COM1 and resets is 0. The error message I get is Access is denied failed to open \.\COM1. So essentialy what I am asking is how do I do a kernel debug on windows 7 which is  a virtualbox from my local computer running windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not try to connect until the VM is running and Virtualbox creates the server end of the pipe. It can take several attempts to catch the right moment.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. Could you list me the steps involved for windbg and the virtual box so I know my set up is correct?

Comment: Ok, so step 1. Start the VM and let it actually run for few seconds, but not too long or it stops waiting for connection; 2. Start windbg session. It is simple but timing is important. Ask a co-worker to show you. Of course assuming that COM port settings in the VM are correct.

Comment: Don't vote me down until you get at least one other reply, pal.

Comment: I didn't vote you down lol. I got it so i'll vote you up. Thanks!

Comment: I had the wrong name in my pipe name. But after that I just had to reboot the vm in debug mode and it worked. Still haven't got it working for visual studios tho. I am not sure what to put for target pipename as windbg only had host pipe name.

Comment: Thank you. Visual studio without 3rd party add-ons IIRC connects over network, not serial port.